# [Python3.6]Facebook Graph API to retrieve Facebook page's "About" description

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve the post from a public Facebook page (About > More Info > About), for example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook/about/?ref=page_internal
```

I have created a Facebook Graph app at https://developers.facebook.com/

I have generated User token here (and debugged it to extend the expiration):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

The code to retrieve the About section is below:

```
import fb
oauth_access_token = "myextendedaccesstoken"
graph = fb.graph.api(oauth_access_token)
site_info = graph.get_object(cat="single", id="https://www.facebook.com/pg/facebook/about/?ref=page_internal", fields="about")
site_info
```

Nevertheless, I am getting an error:

```
{'error': {'code': 104,
'fbtrace_id': 'C3p9UsYu5Bs',
'message': 'An access token is required to request this resource.',
'type': 'OAuthException'}}
```

I tried to submit the app for review (just in case I need to finish the process for the token to work), but struggling with the permissions. 
So far, I've selected three permissions that are the closest to what I need (reading Facebook's public organizational pages):

```
business_management
group_access_member_info
manage_pages
```

My questions: 
-Are the above permissions correct for my purpose? 
-Is it possible to use the generated token without submitting the Facebook App for review?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not how to do API requests. I would recommend you read the documentation at developers.facebook.com/docs . When you call the API you call graph.facebook.com/....

Comment: You should test your requests in Graph API Explorer first of all as well, before you start to do your own coding. Then at least you will know if you are having a problem with the request itself, or your attempt to perform it. The `?id=http://somesite` syntax is to request data about Open Graph objects, _external_ websites, not native Facebook pages. For those, you should use the page name or id. And if this is for a page you have no admin access to, then you will of course have to submit your app for review - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: @WizKid, I've read the documentation, the link to the site is in my question, and I was able to find the documentation on teh site. It is not clear for my purposes (how to read "About" sections of the public group pages). My main problem is that API access token is not working without validation by FB. I can't submit for review, because the submission process is asking me to provide detailed info on the login, etc., which is not relevant, since I am not making this app public, but using it on the server-side.

Comment: So can you link to the documentation you found about how to fetch the About section?